# SQL Server : Select Inner Join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, inner-join, distinct

I'm trying to build a query to give me some information doing an inner join on two tables, `tableA` and `tableB`. Here's what they look like:

**TableA**:

```
ClientID     RevNo     RevPurp
------------------------------
123          4557      1
124          4555      1
123          6574      2
123          7857      3
124          8987      2
```

**TableB**:

```
RevNo        ClientID     Active 
------------------- -------------
4557         123          True
6574         123          True
7857         123          True
8987         124          True
4555         124          True
```

Here is what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to do...

```
Select Distinct ClientID 
From TableB 
Inner Join TableA On tableB.RevNo = tblB.RevNo 
Where RevPurp is not 3.
```

`RevPurp` can be 1,2,3 - I'm only trying to select those distinct clients that can have either 1,2 but cannot have a 3.

Looking at the data in the table I should only have 1 record....

```
124
```

Because client 123 has RevPurp 3. So if a client has RevPurp 3, I do not want to see that client when I execute the query!

EDIT - I added a field in TableB called ACTIVE. I need to make sure Active = True when doing my query!

Comment: I fail to see the purpose of TableB.  You can get the results you need from TableA

Comment: @devlincarnate I need to use the table because that's where my WHERE filters are in.

Comment: @Bobski: what `where` filters?  You don't have any on `TableB`.  Unless you have omitted some details.

Comment: These tables are obviously not whole, there are more fields, I need to Select from TableB and inner Join TableA - I will add filters later.

Comment: Well it is not obvious. Please enter enough info so we have the complete problem, ort at least enough of the parts so that we understand the problem.

Comment: @CharlesBretana, my apologies, I edited the question - should have included it before.

Comment: hey no worries, yours is a common issue from new participants. You're trying to keep the question short and concise.  It's a fine line figuring out how much of the real problem is necessary, and how much can (and should be) be left out.

Comment: Another concern: since both tables share the `clientId` and `revNo` columns, are you sure the join condition should not include both columns?  And is the relationship between both tables always 1 to 1?  Or can there be missing rows on either side, etc?

Comment: There is potential that there can be a ClientID in TableA but not in TableB, but in this case there won't be a an innerJoin on RevNo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @devlin mentioned in a comment, you do not need tableB to do this:
You want a list of unique (distinct) ClientIds in TableA where there is no record in tableA with a RevPurp value of 3.

EDIT: adding in the filter predicate on `TableB.Active`

```
Select distinct a.ClientId 
from tableA a join tableb b 
   on b.RevNo = a.RevNo
Where b.Active = 1  -- <===== is Active a BIT field
  and Not exists
   (Select * from tableA 
    Where ClientId = a.ClientId 
       and RevPurp = 3)
```

Comment: I need it select from TableB inner Join to TableA because I need to use tableB for more criteria in the WHERE statement

Comment: Well, then list the criteria you need from TableB (The filtering or sorting rules you need to implement)  as part of your question. Otherwise we are answering the wrong question.

Comment: @CharlesBretana bit

Answer (score 1):

A simple `group by` with a `having` clause should work:

```
select clientId
  from tableA
 group by clientId
having count(*) = count(case when RevPurp <> 3 then 'X' end)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try not in

```
Select Distinct ClientID 
from TableB 
inner join TableA on tableB.RevNo = tblB.RevNo 
where tableA.ClientID not in (select ClienID from tableA where RevPurp = 3)
```